# Restrict Facebook app access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth

I've written a web application which uses Facebook as the main way to authenticate users and collect information. On the home page, there is one button 'Sign in with Facebook', which allows users to sign in to the app.

Is there any way to restrict which users can use the Facebook app, and thus log into my web app, or do I have to handle this separately/manually? My first idea was to add them as 'test users', because my app is still in beta phase, and thus not publicly accessible. But I'm not sure (and I can't find anywhere) how much test users are allowed per app (as this could be up to 1000 users over time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle it manually. A good way to restrict access is to deny access in general, store authorized users and activate their access in a backend. You can´t just get their ID before authorization, because the ID is App Scoped.